# Generating an insert script based on selected rows in Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, scripting

In Sql Server 2005, is there any way, using the official GUI or a third party tool, to select rows in a table and then generate a insert script for the selected rows?

Comment: So instead of a generic insert you want the data specific to the selected row(s), correct?

Comment: Right. My issue is that I insert rows with the SQL Server GUI and then want to copy inserted rows to other servers.

Answer (score 6):

I do not know of tool that lets you do this using a nice GUI, but I do know of a nice stored procedure that you can use to generate inserts, based on select statement.  The script was created by a guy named Narayana Vyas Kondreddi.

You can learn more about the script [here](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/code.htm#inserts).

You would use it like this:

```
EXEC sp_generate_inserts 'titles', @From = "from titles where title like '%Computer%'"
```

It's a real time-saver.

Answer (score 3):

[SQuirreL SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) can do this:

Highlight a SELECT statement, then invoke Session/Scripts/Create data script from SQL.

Comment: I can only get SQuirrel to copy specific columns from the rows into an insert, not the entire row.

Comment: Hm, if you do something like "SELECT * from tableA", then mark the whole statement with the mouse and invoke the menu option given above, it should work. How did you do it?

Comment: I'm having the same problem: Squirrel won't give me an INSERT script on a select(*)

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you to use SQL Tool Belt from RedGate [link text](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Professional_Toolbelt/index.htm)